# OpenSSL binaries for Windows without Visual C++ 2005/2008 Redistributables

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I want to use the Win32 OpenSSL binaries from [Shining Light Productions](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) for the sole purpose of generating self-signed certificates. Unfortunately, my PC has a newer version of Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables, instead of the version recommended by Shining Light Productions.

Since I didn't see any static builds on the download page, what is the latest version of Win32 OpenSSL binaries that doesn't require the Visual C++ 2005/2008 Redistributables?

PS. I know about the alternatives of generating SSL certificates, I'm just interested in OpenSSL binaries.

Comment: Shouldn't be question be "Building OpenSSL under Windows" then?

Comment: No, I'm simply looking for an older version with different runtime requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenSSL Binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) wiki page:

> OpenSSL for Windows
>
> Pre-compiled Win32/64 libraries without external dependencies to the Microsoft Visual Studio Runtime DLLs, except for the system provided `msvcrt.dll`
>
> https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Answer (score 0):

From **[GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)** project:

- [**OpenSSL for Windows**](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) version **0.9.8h**
- requires only **`msvcrt.dll`** and **`msvcp60.dll`**